# Replacing Crestron switches with standard switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, smart-switch

We bought a house that has a Crestron system and it's been unbearable with lights frequently not working, coming on as if by magic, etc. We had a Crestron installer look at the system and $400 later after "reprogramming" we're still having the same problems. I'd like to consider replacing every Crestron switch in the house with standards. There are hot and neutral wires in all the boxes I've opened. How would standard switches be wired in this situation?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are these 120V wallbox-controls, or a system with low-voltage controls and a central control panel?

Comment: What makes you think those wires are neutrals?

Comment: sounds like a 1 to 1 replacement, nothing special. a pic might help.

Comment: These are 120V. I don't find anything low voltage.  I think the white wires are neutrals because my tester doesn't light up and beep when touching those wires with the breaker on vs. lighting up and beeping when touching the black wires (Excluding the one bare end black wire that you see in the photo. I'm not sure what that or the red wire are doing in the box.) Not sure what you mean, dandavis, by a 1 to 1 replacement. Hope you'll clarify.  Thanks for responses so far, folks.

Comment: The problem with these systems or the older ones is the communications is wireless and today there is so much wireless data they (the older ones can get confused) could you add the model number of your controller? These are usually high end systems and depending on model there may be fixes to reduce unwanted activation. (Removal may also reduce your home’s value).

Comment: Yeah -- this system is indeed a wireless setup, and the whites are all neutrals here.  Can you get us photos of the insides of an exemplar light fixture or two please, or is there a central control panel somewhere in the house?

Comment: Added photo of Crestron hub. Just let me know if there's other info that would be helpful. Added photo of the light fixture controlled by the switch in the first photo. There's not a separate electrical control panel for the Crestron system - just the hub and a touchscreen

Comment: @Jim -- what wires connect to said hub?

Comment: No "electrical" wires connect to the hub. It's just an ethernet cable.

Comment: Also, I currently have both the hub and touchscreen (both ethernet connected to our network) unplugged. It makes no difference to the operation, or lack of operation in my case, of any lights in the house.

Comment: @dandavis Do you have any other thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ed Beal Do you have any other thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Do you have any other thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jim -- there has to be something in the system that actually yanno, turns the lights on and off...trace one of the lighting circuits starting from your breaker box and see where it goes?

Comment: @threephaseeel some of the older touch screens were full blown computers that ran the system, smart phones changed things quite a bit, I believe I have an old p1 9” touchscreen someplace out in my shop, it’s only ~2” thick. It was used for programming the later systems that had onboard memory and did not need the computer except to program them.

Comment: I'd say that if you had someone from Crestron come out to reprogram the system and paid $400 for the service, that they should come out and make it good, since it's still not working.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input. I really just want to go to dumb switches. I'll definitely put everything on ebay and try to recoup some of the $400 I'm out with the Crestron dealer. I'll try the suggestion from @EdBeal

Comment: @EdBeal -- yeah, I was referring to the box that had the relays/dimmers that turned the lights on/off/up/down

Answer (score 1):

I have only worked on a few of these systems.
Each switch has a hot and neutral.

If you cap the neutral or remove that pigtail then the black(s) can be moved to a simple snap switch.

If you decommission everything I would put the controller and all the switches on E-bay you might just pay for all of your replacements.

The other option is switching to WiFi type switches and a hub.
These are possibly a bit smarter and can be controlled through your smart phone and WiFi.

In either case going with simple snap switches and capping or removing the pig tail or a different smarter type of smart switch and hub(s) setup should not be hard because you have hot and neutral at each location.